Can I Use chocolate teddy, Graham crackers in place of regular chocolate ground crackers
I’m making a chocolate peanut butter cheesecake. It calls for chocolate graham crackers. What do you think about using chocolate teddy grams?

are they baked with cocoa powder or coated in chocolate?  You might want to compare the ingredients list and nutrition info (sugars, sodium, fat, etc) to see how similar they are
